# PowerShell execution speed improvement

Tags: arrays, performance, powershell, arraylist

I've played around with some sorting algorithms written in PowerShell last night. Beforehand I had to generate an array of random ints so I have something I can sort. However, the time to generate the array took me too long and so I improved my code to run as fast as possible.

My final code looks like this:

```
$max = 1000000
$RndNumberArr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$ran = New-Object Random
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++)
{ 
    [void]$RndNumberArr.Add($ran.Next(0,$max))    
}
```

With Measure-Command, I got an average execution time of about 2.5s.

I've noticed that using an `ArrayList` is faster then using an Array with fixed size (which doesn't make much sense to me, is there something faster?)

Also, using the .NET method `random.Next()`, instead of the CMDLet `Get-Random` improves the speed a good amount as well (saved like 30s).

Are there any downsides of using the .NET methods?

Also I think that using

```
[void]$RndNumberArr.Add($ran.Next(0,$max))
```

to prevent the `Array.Add` output is slightly faster than using

```
$RndNumberArr.Add($ran.Next(0,$max)) > $null
```

Am I right?

The CMDLet is with a clear time difference the slowest.

```
$RndNumberArr.Add($ran.Next(0,$max)) | Out-Null
```

Does my computer hardware (CPU especially) affect the PowerShell execution speed or is the speed capped at some point? If so, is there a way to enhance the assigned system resources for a speed improvement?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, there aren't any downsides of using .net methods besides readability and "best practices".  But when you get into performance improvements like you're doing, sometimes they're the only method to get the improvements.

Comment: As an aside: Note [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8986) to add support for creating multiple values to the `Get-Random` cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is generating a large list of random ints, I'd suggest avoiding list management altogether:

```
$r = [Random]::new()
$max = 1000000
$list = foreach ($i in 1..$max)
{
    $r.Next(0, $max)
}
```

This code ran almost twice as fast compared to using a `for` loop (roughly 1.4-1.5 seconds versus 2.6 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

[Maximilian Burszley's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019332/45375) provides the fastest solution, for two reasons:

- It lets *PowerShell* construct the array for you, by implicitly collecting all outputs from the `foreach` loop.
- It uses `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), combined with `foreach` (`1..$max`) rather than a `for` loop with *arithmetic*; while a `foreach` loop with range syntax consumes more memory - the array of indices must be constructed as a whole, up-front - it is noticeably faster than an arithmetic `for` loop.

  - As a general rule, anything that is performed *by the PowerShell engine itself* as opposed to by *user code* performs much better.

---

> I've noticed that using an ArrayList is faster then using an Array with fixed size

That is because **.NET arrays are *fixed-size* collections, so you cannot *add* elements** to an array in order to construct it iteratively.

PowerShell hides that fact from you by allowing you to do **`$array += ...`**, but what that does behind the scenes is to create a *new* array every time, comprising all original elements plus the new one. Therefore, in a loop with many iterations, **a new array must be created in each iteration**, which results in very **poor performance**.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5643) suggests a potential future enhancement to allow constructing inherently extensible lists in a PowerShell-idiomatic way.

> Also, I think that using
> `[void]$RndNumberArr.Add($ran.Next(0,$max))`
> to prevent the `Array.Add` output is slightly faster than using
> `$RndNumberArr.Add($ran.Next(0,$max)) > $null`
> Am I right?

Yes, with output from *expressions* `[void]` is faster, though you should **consider using the equally fast `$null = ...` instead for syntactical convenience**, because `=` has the lowest operator precedence, so you needn't worry about enclosing the RHS in `(...)`, unlike with `[void]`, given that *casts* have high precedence.

---

> Are there any downsides of using the .NET methods?

Let's state the ***upside*** first:

Being able to call virtually any .NET type's methods is a great PowerShell extensibility feature - whenever PowerShell doesn't provide a feature via its cmdlets/functions and operators or doesn't provide it with sufficient performance, .NET types' methods usually do.

That said, there *are* **downsides**:

- Syntactically, **method syntax** (`(...)` around the list of arguments, which are `,`-separated) **can cause confusion with PowerShell's argument-mode (command) syntax** (shell-like: no `(...)` around the arguments, which are *whitespace*-separated); `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher can help you detect inadvertent attempts to call PowerShell cmdlets/functions with method syntax.
- While a rare occurrence, **it is possible for new method overloads introduced in later .NET framework versions to break existing code** owing to PowerShell's *late-bound* nature: if the new overloads happen to cause existing code to bind to them instead, things can break.

  - A concrete example is the introduction of a new overload to the `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::sizeof()` method in .NET 4.5.1 - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3809#issuecomment-302804271
- **Help for .NET types' methods isn't integrated with PowerShell's help system**.

---

> Does my computer hardware (CPU especially) affect the PowerShell execution speed or is the speed capped at some point? If so, is there a way to enhance the assigned system resources for a speed improvement?

There's no *throttling* of CPU use that I'm  aware of, but I can't speak to if/how multiple CPUs/cores are utilized - if anyone knows, do tell us.

Generally speaking, *if* suitable to a given task, *parallelization* may speed things up, and there are several ways to do that:

- Use *background jobs* with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)
- As a faster alternative, use the *PowerShell SDK* to create multiple runspaces per process, something that the community-provided [`PoshRSJob` module](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) provides in a nicely packaged, PowerShell-idiomatic form.
- In Windows PowerShell, *workflows* offer parallel execution.
- Finally - again, *if* feasible for the task at hand - you can parallelize execution by spreading a task across multiple *computers* with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command).